# EOS-Mainnet won't work. Can't run nodeos

Tags: eos

nodeos won't work. Getting:

925748ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:202          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin
Failed to initialize

Comment: Would you please better describe your issue?

Comment: I built EOS on my machine and when I  attempt to run nodeos I can't initialize chain:

```3214892ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:206          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin
Failed to initialize```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue raises because of database dirty flag. Try:

```
nodeos --hard-replay
```